# How does the Rambam understand the end of Shir Hashirim?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, rambam, shemos-sacred-names, shir-hashirim

The Rambam in Hilchos Yesodei HaTorah, 6:9, [states](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/904982/jewish/Yesodei-haTorah-Chapter-Six.htm):

> Every mention of the name "Shelomoh" in the Song of Songs is sacred, except [8:12]: "You, Shelomoh, may have the thousand." (trans. by Chabad.org)

Looking at [the passage](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16452) in question, however, it is unclear how the Rambam would understand this:

> Shelomoh (sacred) had a vineyard in Ba'al Hamon; he gave the vineyards to the watchmen, a man/each would bring with its fruit a thousand silver. My vineyard, mine, before me; the thousand to you, Shelomoh (secular), and two hundreds to those who watch its fruit. (8:11-12, trans. mine)

If the first Shelomoh refers to God, why are we giving a thousand to the second Shelomoh (presumably King Solomon)? How does the Rambam understand this?

Answer (score 1):

The source of Rambam is in [Shvuot 35:2](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=26&daf=35b&format=text), start with the words "כל שלמה האמורין בשה"ש קדש".

There are some exception that are brought to this rule.
But according to one of the opinions the Shelomoh that you brought refers to God, and division of money is number of people that a King may kill.

> אמר שמואל מלכותא דקטלא חד משיתא בעלמא לא מיענשא שנאמר כרמי שלי לפני האלף לך שלמה למלכותא דרקיעא ומאתים לנוטרים את פריו למלכותא דארעא
>
> Shmuel said, the kingdom that kill 1/6 of the world in not punished, as said "My vineyard, mine, before me; the thousand to you Shelomoh" - to the kingdom of havens,  "and two hundreds to those who watch its fruit" - to the kingdom of the earth.

Anyway, according to every opinion the verse "הנה מטתו שלשלמה" does not refers to God. I don't know how Ramba"m would explain this one (but this is another question).